# How to get MySQL error parameters?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

In case of a MySQL error, such as duplicate entry, I want to get the name of the field that caused the problem. I'm doing it like this:

```
$err = $mysqli->error;
$errno = $mysqli->errno;
...
if ($errno == 1062)
{
    $begin = strpos($err, "' for key '") + 11;
    $end = strlen($err) - 1;
    $arg = substr($err, $begin, $end - $begin);
}
```

and so `$arg` stores the name. This doesn't feel like a super solid way to do it though since, as far as I know, there is no guarantee that the format of the error stays the same from version to version and database to database.

Is there a more direct way to get the name of that field?

Comment: That is a problem. I would use store whole error message or get value by regex. You need to know how parse error value by error code. This is a problem if errors can be changed by new version sql engine. If you need that I would make array errorCode => regex how to get certain value.

Comment: Why do you want it? In a sanely designed application one don't need the name. There shouldn't be many unique indexes on the same table.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Well lets say I have a table of students, each with their unique student ID, username for school e-services, phone number, social security number and e-mail for example

Comment: Well, if you want to check, then just do a select first.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20727269/database-handling-of-unique-constraint-violation

Answer (score 0):

You would do a nested CASE statement as follows. The result will return the fields with a duplicate entry. If more than 1 duplicate entry it will respond for each one.

```
   SELECT PD.column_name1, PD.column_name2, PD.column_name3 FROM table_name WHERE PD.column_name1 = value1, PD.column_name2 = value2, PD.column_name3 = value3 AS PD (SELECT CASE
      WHEN PD.column_name1 = value1 THEN "column_name1" 
      WHEN PD.column_name2 = value2 THEN "column_name2" 
      WHEN PD.column_name3 = value3 THEN "column_name3")
```