# .jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry in Spring JPA against @Column(unique = true)

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

```
@Column(unique = true) 
private String name;
```

I need to write @ExceptionHandler to handle DataIntegrityViolationException through @RestControllerAdvice, and the expected output should be like.

Expected Output:-
{
    "name": "Admin_User already exists"
}

Tried with below code :-

```
@ExceptionHandler(DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
public ResponseEntity<?> dataIntegrityException(DataIntegrityViolationException exception) {
    String exceptionMessage = exception.getMostSpecificCause().getMessage();
    String responseMessage = exceptionMessage.substring(exceptionMessage.indexOf("'") + 1);
    responseMessage = responseMessage.substring(0, responseMessage.indexOf("'"));
    HashMap<String, String> errorMap = new HashMap<>();
    errorMap.put("UniqueConstraint", responseMessage + " already exists");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(errorMap, HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
}
```

Which results in below output :-

{
    "UniqueConstraint": "Asd12345 already exists"
}

How can i replace "UniqueConstraint" with the generic key. So, that it picks the entity which s throwing the below exception.

Could someone help with getting the expected output as :- 
Expected Output:-
{
    "name": "Asd12345 already exists"
}

How to get name as key in response?

Exception:--

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'simple_role1a1qa1' for key 'UK_8sewwnpamngi6b1dwaa88askk'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
```

Comment: That is correct. So what is your question? And please format your code.

Comment: My Question is how to handle this scenario and send the response to front in JSON format, as "name": "Role name already exists".

Comment: Please update your question to reflect your requirements. Use a Spring Exception Handler. You can find many examples and tutorials on the web. For example here: https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring

Comment: I have added the detailed description now. Could you please suggest ?

Comment: @ExceptionHandler(DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
 public ResponseEntity<?> dataIntegrityException(DataIntegrityViolationException exception){
  String exceptionMessage = exception.getMostSpecificCause().getMessage();
  String responseMessage = exceptionMessage.substring(exceptionMessage.indexOf("'") + 1);
  responseMessage = responseMessage.substring(0, responseMessage.indexOf("'"));
  
  HashMap<String, String> errorMap = new HashMap<>();
  errorMap.put("UniqueConstraint", responseMessage + " already exists");
     return new ResponseEntity<>(errorMap, HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
}

Comment: Is it because of this line:  errorMap.put("UniqueConstraint", responseMessage + " already exists");  Why don't you write "name" instead of "UniqueContraint"?

Comment: I want a generic solution. I have so many @Column(unique = true) entities in models. I want a generic solution that, it would pick the key for which it is throwing the error.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20727269/database-handling-of-unique-constraint-violation

Comment: that didn't help, Could someone help with the common way to handle this exception for all models having unique validation over it.